# Can every real continuous function be approximated by either a convex or concave function on an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity, convex-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

If $0\leq a < b\leq 1;\ p: [a,b]\to [f(m),f(M)] \subset [0,1],$ where $p(m) = \min_{x\in(a,b)} p(x) $ and $p(M) = \max_{x\in(a,b)} p(x), $ is a non-constant continuous function, then $ h_p(x):[0,1]\to[0,1];\ h_p(x):=\frac{p((b-a)x+a)-p(m)}{p(M)-p(m)}$ is the function $p$ but translated and stretched to have domain $[0,1]$ and range $[0,1].$

> Let $f: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a non-constant continuous function. Does there exist an
> interval $(a,b)$ where $0\leq a < b \leq 1$ on which $f$ is non-constant, and a continuous concave or convex
> function $g: (a,b)\to [0,1],$ such that
>
> $$ \left\vert f_p(x) - g_p(x) \right\vert < \frac{1}{100}
>  \quad \forall x\in [0,1],\ $$
> where $f_p$ and $h_p$ are as defined above?

$$$$

I tried proof by contradiction but didn't get anywhere.

I also thought about using [Weierstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%2C%20the%20Weierstrass,desired%20by%20a%20polynomial%20function.), since every polynomial has concave and convex sections. But I think this theorem is about global distance ("uniformly approximated"), not relative distance like in the inequality, so I don't think it helps.

Maybe something like the Weierstrass function is a counter-example but I don't know.

Comment: Similar to Weierstrass, but with a sine wave period instead at each step instead of the triangle...

Comment: Is that $\forall x \in (0, 1)$ instead of $\forall x \in (a, b)$? If so, I think this new formulation is equivalent to the previous one, except that it once again excludes functions $f$ where $f(a) = f(b)$.

Comment: I once more tried to make the question have no incorrectness.

Comment: If you are allowed to make the interval $(a,b)$ as short as you like, then your approximating function $g$ may be chosen to be constant.  From the definition of "continuous".

Comment: For $h(x) = x$, choose $a=1/100$ and $b=2/100$.  Then $|h(x) - 1/100| < 1/100$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

Comment: @GEdgar you're right. My function still isn't quite as intended...

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<\epsilon<\min(\frac{1}{800}(f(M)-f(m)), 1/2)$. By Weierstrass approximation theorem, there exists a polynomial $g:[0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon/2$, for every $x\in[0, 1]$. If $g$ is linear, it is convex everywhere, and if it is not, then it has degree at least 2, so its second derivative is not identically zero, and we may take an interval $[a, b]$ where $g$ is convex (or concave). If the range of $g$ is not in $[0, 1]$, we can restrict even more $[a, b]$ so that $g$ exceeds only one of $0$ or $1$. If it exceeds $1$, take $a, b$ such that $g>1/2$ in $[a, b]$, and thus, taking $\bar g=g-\epsilon/2$, the range of $\bar g$ in $[a, b]$ is within $[0, 1]$, $|\bar g-f|<\epsilon$ uniformly and $\bar g$ is still convex (or concave).

Under all this considerations, we can assume that $g$ defined over $[a, b]$ is convex, non-constant, its range is within $[0, 1]$ and $|g-f|<\epsilon$ uniformly.

Let $g(m')$ (resp. $g(M')$) be the min (resp. max) of $g$ in $[a, b]$. Then
$$g(m')\le g(x)<f(x)+\epsilon,$$
so that $g(m')< f(m)+\epsilon$, and
$$f(m)\le f(x) < g(x)+\epsilon,$$ so that $g(m')>f(m)-\epsilon$. In a similar way, we have that $|f(M)-g(M')|<\epsilon$.

Now, if $r(x)=f((b-a)x+a)$, $s(x)=g((b-a)x+a)$ and
$$d(x)=f_p(x)-g_p(x),$$ as
$$r(x)-f(m)-2\epsilon < s(x)-g(m') < r(x)-f(m)+2\epsilon$$
and
\begin{align*}
d(x)&=\frac{r(x)-f(m)}{f(M)-f(m)} - \frac{s(x)-g(m')}{g(M')-g(m')} \\\
&= \frac{n(x)}{(f(M)-f(m))(g(M')-g(m'))},
\end{align*}
where $$n(x)=(g(M')-g(m'))(r(x)-f(m))-(f(M)-f(m))(s(x)-g(m')),$$
then
\begin{align*}
n(x)&= (g(M')-g(m'))(r(x)-f(m))-(f(M)-f(m))(s(x)-g(m'))\\\
&<(f(M)-f(m)+2\epsilon)(r(x)-f(m))-(f(M)-f(m))(r(x)-f(m)-2\epsilon)\\\
&=2\epsilon(r(x)+f(M)-2f(m))
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
n(x)&= (g(M')-g(m'))(r(x)-f(m))-(f(M)-f(m))(s(x)-g(m'))\\\
&>(f(M)-f(m)-2\epsilon)(r(x)-f(m))-(f(M)-f(m))(r(x)-f(m)+2\epsilon)\\\
&=-2\epsilon(r(x)+f(M)-2f(m)),
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
|d(x)| &< 2\epsilon\frac{r(x)+f(M)-2f(m)}{(f(M)-f(m))(g(M')-g(m'))}\\\
&\le 4\epsilon\frac{1}{f(M)-f(m)-2\epsilon} \\\
&\le \frac{4\epsilon}{f(M)-f(m)-(f(M)-f(m))/2} \\\
&<\frac{1}{100}.
\end{align*}

The annoying part is ensuring that the range of $g$ is within $[0, 1]$